# Terraform: google_sql_database_instance not being created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create a CloudSQL instance using terraform but its not even trying to create it appears: The CloudSQL dashboard doesnt change

[image]

```
google_sql_database_instance.db-instance: Still creating... [9m41s elapsed]
google_sql_database_instance.db-instance: Still creating... [9m51s elapsed]
google_sql_database_instance.db-instance: Still creating... [10m1s elapsed]
```

It eventually timesout. Why is that?

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "db-instance" {
  # depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private-vpc-connection]

  name = "sonarqube"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_9_6"
  region = "asia-southeast1"
  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"
    # ip_configuration {
    #   private_network = google_compute_network.private-network.self_link
    # }
  }
}
```

I even removed the private networking parts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so I set TF_LOG=DEBUG and saw

```
2019-11-23T22:04:41.365+0800 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-google-beta_v3.0.0-beta.1_x4: 2019/11/23 22:04:41 [DEBUG] Dismissed an error as retryable. Waiting for other concurrent Cloud SQL operations to finish - googleapi: Error 409: The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request., invalidState
```

After some googling, I found https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20972

> This happens because instance names cannot be reused for up to a week after it's deleted.

So I guess the issue is because I am attempting to create an instance with a name that was recently used ...

Comment: Indeed in order to be able to reuse a name already used in a new CloudSQL instance, you have to [wait for 7 days](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/delete-instance). In case it's really important for you to reuse the name and you have a support package on Google Cloud Platform support, you can open a ticket about it.